# Fire callback from AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sending some information to a factory from another service, and when I put this information in the factory for access, what I am trying to achieve is something to the effect of - when I fire the callback which sets information, I would like to then immediately send that information into my controller connected to the factory. Something like setting a watch on a variable, but what would be even better is if I could set an observer pattern or something.

Here is the factory right now :

```
 function() {

            var productRoutes = {};
            var currentState = {}

            productRoutes.callback = function(routeName, routeVars) {
                currentState[routeName] = routeVars;
            };

            productRoutes.getState = function(){
                return currentState;
            }

            return productRoutes;
        });
```

So I fire the callback and set the vars in currenstate. I have something inside of the controller calling the getState immediately, however it is coming back empty because the other function has not (or is in  the process of) fired.

So I'm trying to figuire a way to have the factory send the information (currentState) down into the controller and trigger a function to change configurations in the controller - again something to the extent of a watch? but i'm  not sure how to tie that to a factory. It would be neat if I did not have to have a watch, and the factory could send the new information as soon as it's changed and trigger a function, is this possible? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why not `$rootScope.$broadcast` and just listen in the controller?

Comment: @NickTomlin is a very big app, trying to avoid methods like that if i can. Thanks!

Comment: I understand. You could just extend EventEmitter (or another event implementation) onto your factory and have your controller listen to it.